# How to know which APIs zombie.js have?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zombie.js

In [the example](http://zombie.js.org/) of Zombie.js there is code as following:

```
const Browser = require('zombie');
// ...
const browser = new Browser();
// ...
browser
    .fill('email',    'zombie@underworld.dead')
    .fill('password', 'eat-the-living')
    .pressButton('Sign Me Up!', done);
```

And I didn't find *fill*, *pressButton* in its document, so I don't know which APIs it has, at last I solved what I need by reading its source code.

My question is: How can I know its APIs?
It didn't list them because these methods come from another module? If so, what's the module? Or they're so common/obvious so docs are needed?

Comment: Documentation for pressButton can be found [here](https://zombie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pythonzombie.html?highlight=pressbutton#zombie.browser.Browser.pressButton), on that site you can just search or navigate to the methods you need documentation for.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I'm still confused that why I didn't find any link to that page in zombie.js.org which I believe it's the home page?